# Unable to Scrape Content that comes after a Comment Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, comments

I am trying to scrape the tables from the following page:

https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/CHA/CHA193805220.shtml

When I reach the html for the batting tables I encounter a very long comment which contains the html for the table

```
<div id="all_WashingtonSenatorsbatting" class="table_wrapper table_controls">
     <div class="section_heading">
     <div class="section_heading_text">
     <div class="placeholder"></div>
     <!-- 
        <div class="table_outer_container">
        .....
        -->
     <div class="table_outer_container mobile_table">
     <div class="footer no_hide_long">
```

Where the last two `div` are what I am interested in scraping and everything in between the `<!--` and the `-->` is a comment which happens to contain a copy of the table in the `table_outer_container` class below.

The problem is that when I read the page source into beautiful soup it does will not read anything after the comment within the `table_wrapper` class `div` which contains everything. The following code illustrates the problem:

```
batting = page_source.find('div', {'id':'all_WashingtonSenatorsbatting'})
divs = batting.find_all('div')
len(divs)
```

gives me

```
Out[1]: 3
```

When there are obviously 5 `div` children under the `div id="all_WashingtonSenatorsbatting"` element.

Even when I extract the comment using

```
from bs4 import Comment
for comments in soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)):
     comments.extract()
```

The resulting soup still doesn't contain the last two `div` elements I want to scrape. I am trying to play with the code using regular expressions but so far no luck, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found workable solution, By using the following code I extract the comment (which brings with it the last two `div` elements I wanted to scrape), process it again in BeautifulSoup and scrape the table

```
s = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'table_wrapper'})[0]
comment = t(text=lambda x: isinstance(x, Comment))[0]
newsoup = BeautifulSoup(comment, 'html.parser')
table = newsoup.find('table')
```

It took me a while to get to this and would be interested to see if anyone comes up with any other solutions or can offer an explanation of how this problem came to be.